# variable defined in switch in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

When I tried to assign a pointer in switch statement, the 
compile gave me an error warning, but when I debugged the code by declaring 
the pointer outside the switch statement. The code 
syntactically passed. Why? Can anyone explain it to me? Thank you!

Before I debugged:

```
void Left_Balance(treeNode **T)
{
    treeNode *p=(*T)->left;  
    switch(p->bf)
    {
        case LH:
            p->bf=(*T)->bf=EQ;
            L_Rotate(T);
            break;
        case RH:
             treeNode *q = p->right;  
            switch(q->bf)
           {
               case LH:
                   (*T)->bf=RH;
                   p->bf=EQ;
                   break;
               case EQ:
                   (*T)->bf=q->bf=EQ;
                   break;
               case RH:
                   p->bf=LH;
                   (*T)=EQ;
                   break;
           }
            q->bf=EQ;
            R_Rotate(&p);
            L_Rotate(T);
            break;
    }
}
```

After I debugged :

```
void Left_Balance(treeNode **T)
{
    treeNode *p=(*T)->left;
    treeNode *q;     //Here is the difference 
    switch(p->bf)
    {
        case LH:
            p->bf=(*T)->bf=EQ;
            L_Rotate(T);
            break;
        case RH:
            q = p->right;    //Here is the difference 
            switch(q->bf)
           {
               case LH:
                   (*T)->bf=RH;
                   p->bf=EQ;
                   break;
               case EQ:
                   (*T)->bf=q->bf=EQ;
                   break;
               case RH:
                   p->bf=LH;
                   (*T)=EQ;
                   break;
           }
            q->bf=EQ;
            R_Rotate(&p);
            L_Rotate(T);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I don't think there is any dynamic memory allocation occuring in this code. As far as I know dynamic memory allocation in C only occurs with calls to `calloc()` or `malloc()`.

Comment: One potential error could be caused if you're using a C89. In C89 declaring variables anywhere besides the top of the scope (directly below an opening  curly brace) is invalid.

Comment: The error is expected expression

Comment: The compile just spat out "expected expression"? Please edit your question to include the full error message.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is the full error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your first version `treeNode *q = p->right;` is not in a block (`{}`)

an other possibility was to add that block

```
    case RH:
  {
    treeNode *q = p->right;  
        switch(q->bf)
       {
           case LH:
               (*T)->bf=RH;
               p->bf=EQ;
               break;
           case EQ:
               (*T)->bf=q->bf=EQ;
               break;
           case RH:
               p->bf=LH;
               (*T)=EQ;
               break;
       }
        q->bf=EQ;
        R_Rotate(&p);
        L_Rotate(T);
        break;
  }
```

---

Warning

> ```
>  (*T)=EQ;
> ```

is very suspicious because `*T` is a `treeNode *` and EQ is not one because of `case EQ`

Probably you want

```
 (*T)->bf = EQ;
```

---

(edit)

As @dbush indicates it is enough to add a statement between the label and the declaration, but to not put the declaration in a block is very dangerous, look at that code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  switch (argc) {
  case 1:
    puts("case 1");

    int i = 123;

    puts("i initialized and continue in case 2");

  case 2:
    printf("in case2, i values : %d\n", i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

What about *i* used in *printf* if the program is called with an argument initializing *argc* is 2 ?

Note *gcc* accepts that code but not *g++* without the option `-fpermissive` and with that option the code is compiled without `case 2:`

This is why I proposed to add a block.

Answer (score 0):

```
    case RH:
         treeNode *q = p->right;
```

Here you have a label right before a **declaration**.  A label can only come before a **statement**.  You can fix this by adding an empty statement right before the declaration that the label can be associated with:

```
    case RH:
         ;
         treeNode *q = p->right;
```

Comment: This is right, but dangerous because can introduce crosses initialization in case a _break_ is missing

Comment: what is a label? Can you guys answer me??